# Why can't I replace backslashes in a string containing double quotes using replace function?

Tags: python, replace

```
# string containing backslash and double quotes, cannot replace backslash
text = 'Sleep Profile will compare a user\'s trends to what\'s typical for "their" age'
text.replace('\\', '')
'Sleep Profile will compare a user\'s trends to what\'s typical for "their" age'

# string containing backslash without double quotes, can replace backslash
text = 'Sleep Profile will compare a user\'s trends to what\'s typical for their age'
text.replace('\\', '')
'Sleep Profile will compare a user's trends to what's typical for their age'
```

I don't understand why it can't detect the backslash or how to actually achieve my goal of being able to remove them with the original sentence with double quotes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works on my end. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: You can't replace the backslash because there is no backslash. The backslash in the litteral string is only written in the source code to escape the quote. `print` the string and you won't see it. Here, as you probably are working in the REPL, you get the `repr` of the string.

Comment: That is to say, `'\''` and `"'"` are the _exact same string_ (stored the same way in memory, 100% identical to each other). Neither one of them contains an actual backslash; one of them is just printed with a backslash as part of the escaping syntax.

Comment: What you probably want to do is `print(yourstring)` instead of just evaluating `yourstring` letting the REPL do its default thing, which is basically equivalent to `print(repr(yourstring))`; because it's that `repr()`esentation in Python syntax that adds the escapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you're testing it on interactive.

If you notice, on the second example the string is represented by double quotes and not single quotes as the first one.

[image]

In order to keep the single quotes and the double quotes, on interactive, it escapes the single quote on console. However, if you log it to a file, you would see the single quote there

Edit: Added image to better understanding